# AES 128 bit with ECB ciphermode algorithm decrypts correctly with an invalid key?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

Hi i am learning Encryption / Decryption part. I have created two methods for Encryption / Decryption using **AES 128** bit with **ECB** cipher mode and **PKCS7** padding.

Below is the code.

```
public class EncClass
    {
        public string Encrypt(string text)
        {

            byte[] src = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("contactcentre");
            RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.KeySize = 128;

            using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, null))
            {
                byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
                encrypt.Dispose();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
            }
        }

        public string Decrypt(string text)
        {

            byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
            RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
            byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("contactcentrT");
            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, null))
            {
                byte[] dest = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
                decrypt.Dispose();
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest);
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice that in Encryption i have passed **contactcentre** key and in decryption I have passed **contactcentrT**. It is doing proper encryption and decryption in that case.

```
    var encString = encClass.Encrypt(@"manoj");
    var decString = encClass.Decrypt(encString);
```

Though my both keys are not matching, still it is working properly. Just wanted to know how this could happen?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing invalid key to `aes.CreateEncryptor` (and `CreateDecryptor`). Valid key sizes for AES are 128, 192 and 256, and your key is 13*8=104 bits. If you try to assign it to `aes.Key` - that will throw exception. However, `aes.CreateEncryptor` has a bug and it does not correctly validate key size if key size is less than block size (less than 128 bits), despite stating explicitly in documentation that "The key size must be 128, 192, or 256 bits". This bug is fixed in .NET Core by the way (at least in version 2) where it correctly throws exception for your code.

So, since you are passing invalid key and `CreateEncryptor` by mistake allowed it - you are not really encrypting with AES and anything can happen. For example if you pass key of 1 byte (or 2, or 7) - index out of range exception will be thrown. My assumption (by looking at source code) is algorithm implementation assumes key size in bytes is divisable by 4, and uses those 4-byte blocks. First 12 characters of your key are the same, and the rest (be it 1,2 or 3 characters) are not used, because number of 4-byte blocks is calculated as `keySize / 4` (and 13 / 4 = 3).

Anyway, any assumptions of why this happens does not matter much, because algorithm is executed with invalid input and any results produced by doing that are irrelevant.

Given that info - never pass key directly to `aes.CreateEncryptor` but assign it to `aes.Key` first and then pass that (`aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, iv)`)

Comment: If the implementation uses any of the key the keys will be different and different encrypted data will be produced. Are you are saying that the key is not used at all? Then what key is being used?

Comment: @zaph aes.CreateEncryptor has a bug and it allows keys with size less than 128 bits (which is invalid key for AES). For some such keys it throws exception and for others, like OP key - it just runs algorithm with invalid key. Anything can happen in that case. I described what I think might be happening in answer but that does not matter. Running AES with invalid key is wrong and whatever produced by that is irrelevant garbage.

Comment: I agree that using an invalid key produces unknown results and a KDF should be used. Still there is something else going on here. The OP has not provided sample output. The only answer that can be made with assurance is that correct sized keys should be used. Everything else is guessing and information that may not apply to the question.

Comment: @zaph well that's what I say in answer: "Anyway, any assumptions of why this happens does not matter much, because algorithm is executed with invalid input and any results produced by doing that are irrelevant.". Though I looked at source code for `CreateEncryptor` and pretty sure it assumes key size (in bytes) is divisable by 4 and in case of 13 byte OP key - last byte is not used.

Comment: +1 Exactly .. the bytes are passed directly into the rijndael key expansion without validation .. and the key expansion implementation apparently only operates on full blocks of 4 bytes ..